# VB .NET stop autoscroll

Tags: vb.net, forms, focus, mdiparent

I have a VB .net form (maximized in an MDIParent.) Within the form there is a textbox (near the top) that acts as a search. When text is entered a listview with some items pops up, and you can select an item which then hides the list view and fills in the textbox with the corresponding text. My problem is that any time an item is selected the form scrolls down a little bit, just enough to be really annoying. I've tried setting the focus back to the textbox as well as the parent, and I can't seem to find anything to automatically scroll up on a form that uses auto scroll. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just post the screenshot of the problem.

Comment: I'd set the scroll amount to 0 - not entirely to sure how to do this anymore but you can set it to 0 = top of page.

Comment: I need to see repro code for this.  You can assign the form's AutoScrollPosition to get it back where it was.

Comment: Got it fixed! Thank anyways ppl!!